# JSF 1.2 to 2.0 annotation change

Tags: jsf, annotations, javabeans

I migrated from 1.2 to 2.0 and I moved my managed bean names and scopes from the faces-config.xml to the beans using annotations.

One bean(sessionscoped) has an instance variable which gets the current session as such:
    **private HttpSession httpsess  =                                                                                                          (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);**

And then I call the httpsess variable in any instance method to add stuff to the session. But once I made the annotation changes. The httpsess variable returns null. When I create the variable as a local variable it works fine. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSF 2.x, the creation of `HttpSession` is postponed as much as possible to avoid unnecessary session creation. It will only be created when it is *really* needed. It's apparently not been created yet at the point you're calling it. Passing `false` to `getSession()` means that the container shouldn't auto-create it if it doesn't exist. So if it doesn't exist yet, it will just return `null`.

You need to pass `true` to `getSession()` instead.

```
HttpSession httpsess = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
```

#### See also:

- [`ExternalContext#getSession(boolean)` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSession%28boolean%29)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this is a code smell. What exactly do you need the `HttpSession` for? To get/set some attributes? Why not just make it a property of the current session scoped managed bean? A JSF session scoped managed bean is **by itself** already stored as a session attribute anyway.

Comment: Please follow the 1st link in my above comment. Note that you should be logged in.